# Rails, using has_and_belongs_to_many with abstract Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have abstract model `Detail` that has child models like `Carcass`, `Basis`. Also i have `User` model. Can I use `has_and_belongs_to_many` association between `User` and `Detail`? Could it be inherited to child models? Or do I need to use that association between `User` and each model of `Detal`?

The main goal is to create many-to-many relationship.

I am using rails 4.

Comment: Have you tried both scenarios? Which one works?

Comment: I havent tried it yet. I though someone already has experience on this kind of method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, `has_and_belongs_to_many` can be defined only in parent class. Child classes will inherit this property

Don't forget to create the respective tables to many to many relationships (`carcass_users` and `basis_users`) with:

`rails g migration CreateCarcassUsers`

Inside your migration:

```
class CreateCarcassUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :carcass_users do |t|
      t.integer :carcass_id
      t.integer :user_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: So I need to add some migrations ? Can you provide examples please?

Comment: Thank you :) . I need to create migration for my abstract parent class too?

Comment: My bad, there's no need for abstract class. I'll change it in my answer

Comment: It does not matter which name I will be using first, isn't it? Like `CreateUsersCarcasses`

Comment: It must be in Alphabetical order

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72327/discussion-between-guilherme-carlos-and-mr-d).